# Stale socket connection leak with JNDI/LDAP

Tags: java, memory-leaks, ldap, jndi

I am currently reviewing Oracle's examples how to [manually follow referrals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/referral/throw.html) (case `throw`) in Java/JNDI returned from a directory server via LDAP. The example source code in question can be downloaded [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/referral/src/Throw.java).

The code in question:

```
// Set up environment for creating initial context
Hashtable env = new Hashtable(11);
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
    "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:489/o=JNDITutorial");

// Set referral property to throw ReferralException
env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "throw");

try {
    // Create initial context
    DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

    // Set controls for performing subtree search
    SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
    ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

    // Do this in a loop because we don't know how
    // many referrals there will be
    for (boolean moreReferrals = true; moreReferrals;) {
    try {
        // Perform search
        NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search("", "(objectclass=*)", 
        ctls);

        // Print the answer
        while (answer.hasMore()) {
        System.out.println(">>>" + 
            ((SearchResult)answer.next()).getName());
        }

        // search completes with no more referrals
        moreReferrals = false;

    } catch (ReferralException e) {

        if (! followReferral(e.getReferralInfo())) {
        moreReferrals = e.skipReferral();
        }

        // point to the new context
        if (moreReferrals) {
        ctx = (DirContext) e.getReferralContext();
        }
    }
    }

    // Close the context when we're done
    ctx.close();
} catch (NamingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I consider this code flawed in several ways. The documentation of `DirContext` and `NamingEmuneration` exibit a `close` method wich immediately releases resources. Especially the former holds an open socket to the target server. Not closing it will lead to a socket leakage.

My understanding (flaws) of the code is:

1. NamingEnumeration `answer` is never closed.
2. The very first `DirContext` in not closed in the case of a `NamingException`, should be moved to a `finally` block.
3. The `DirContext` created with `e.getReferralContext()` overwrite `ctx` which means that intermediate referrals as well as the `InitialDirContext` are never closed and lead to leak.

Are my findings correct?

PS: I have also checked Oracle's internal implemenation in the case that `follow` is set and the funny thing is all referral contexts are closed internally.

Disclaimer: I have posted this initially on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/122996/stale-socket-connection-leak) but it was closed because it is not my code. I was advised to try on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the NamingEnumeration, and anything else you get from JNDI that is closeable.

Comment: Beside the `NamingEnumeration` what about 2. and 3.? So, this code is broken, right?

Comment: Yes it is broken. It doesn't close everything that is closeable.

Comment: If you're using OpenLDAP can I direct you to the `chain` overlay, which does all this for you.

Comment: I'd be interested to see it. Though, my code is Java only. Concepts are always good. I'd try it in a C example.

Comment: The chain overlay is part of OpenLDAP. Nothing to do with the client. That's the whole point. You don't have to write crud like this in the first place.

Comment: I have checked [this](http://linuxtopia.org/online_books//network_administration_guides/ldap_administration/overlays_Chaining.html). It won't help me because I am on Active Directory and it does not support the ManageDsaIT control.

Comment: It won't help you because you aren't using OpenLDAP.

Comment: I know that is why I wanted to have this code checked to write my custom code.